# Convert Ros2 Foxy Message to Ros2 Humble

Tags: ros, ros-humble

I currently have 2 projects running, 1 is using Ros2 Foxy and the other is Ros2 Humble, it seems like Ros2 Humble isnt’ entirely compatible with reading old message Format, e.g: I cant read message of type visualization_msgs:MarkerArray , is this a known issue or does any one knows any workaround? I'm thinking of maybe creating a node that subscribe to the required topic in Foxy and maybe convert it into a format that Humble can read?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with 'cannot read message', i.e. how are you trying to read it? with `ros2 topic`, with Rviz, in a node, Python or C++? And what is publishing the marker array, with what QoS? The output of `ros2 topic info /your_topic --verbose` may help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can surmise there being any issues between ROS2 versions is if the message definition itself changes. If there is truly a ROS2 version issue, create a simple message publisher in one version via CLI with `ros2 topic pub` and then `ros2 topic echo` the message via the other ROS2 version. If that pub/sub operation works, then your error is not the message itself. The information you gave in the question is not enough to answer further.

Comment: To add more, there is no expectation or support for publishing and subscribing to messages between distributions of ROS. While it can work in some cases, that is not supported behavior and may break at any time.